# segmentation fault(core dumped) error in c programming

Tags: c

I'm getting segmentation fault(core dumped) error in my c programming. please help me to solve my error.

```
  void calc(float p,float x[10],int n)
     {
      float u;
      int i,k;
      printf("\nenter x for finding f'(x):");
      scanf("%f",&p);
      for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
       {
        if(x[i]<=p && p<x[i+1])
         {
          k=i;
         }
       }
      u=((p-x[k])/(x[k+1]-x[k]));
      printf("u=",u);
     }
```

Comment: don't miss the opportunity to use a debugger on that code. You'll probably find out that one of your indices are too big for the actual array or something.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `printf("u=",u)` will not work as you apparently think it is.

Comment: I suggest man printf, to start with....

Comment: More related to your problem, first of all please try to use useful names for your variables. Then [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), more specifically how to use a debugger to catch crashes when they happen and to locate where they happen.

Comment: Can you post whole code? I want to know what are you passing to the function?

Comment: Lastly: What is the value of `n` you give? Will `i + 1` never be larger than `9`? And are you sure the crash happens in the function you show?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude value of n is way below 9.program crashes when this function is called

Comment: found it: k isn't initialized for sure, enable warnings you'll see

Comment: if the condition never matches in the loop, k is never assigned a value, and is probably very high garbage integer. A debugger allows you to see that instantly

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it was there in the actual code,missed when i copied to here.error persists.pardon

Comment: then [edit] (<=== click here) your question to update the code

Comment: I've edited the code

Comment: Post whole code, there is nothing wrong in this code snippet

Comment: Please do not edit the question so as to invalidate existing answers/comments.  When composing a question, copy/paste only the exact code you tested, else the almost inevitable transcription errors will waste eveybody's time.  If a line generated a segfault, identify it with a code comment eg: '// <<< SEGFAULT HERE'

Answer (score 0):

at the code

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
       {
        if(x[i]<=p && p<x[i+1])
         {
           k=i;
         }
       }
```

x is assumed to be an array of 10 floats, however the loop is counting up to n, when there is no restriction on n (i.e. there is no input validation that n is equal or less than 10). if n is larger than 10, this may cause segmentation fault as you try to access memory outside of the array.

also the line

```
  u=((p-x[k])/(x[k+1]-x[k]));
```

may cause division by zero, and this shall be checked as well.

beside this issues, note that p is actually not a parameter you get from the caller of this method, but input you get from stdin. therefore, it is recommended you set it to be a local variable.
i.e. instead of

```
void calc(float p,float x[10],int n)
    {
```

have

```
void calc( float x[10],int n)
{
float p
```

Comment: p is actually a parameter taken from the user while the program runs

Comment: Yes, but as you assign its value within the function using scanf, you shall not have it declared as function parameter, but as a local function variable. as explained above